# Information Storage for 3 variables

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to create a good way to store 3 variables, two **int**s and a **point** in C# programming.

I thought of a way by using an array of dictionaries

```
 Dictionary<int, Point>[] ItemList = new Dictionary<int, Point>[4];
```

The Idea was that one variable has to be between 1 and 4, so I would have that as the sorting point, or each array location. The 2nd int, has to be between 0 and 15, and the point is on a 4x4 grid. I thought this method would work, and it would have except that You can't have the same key in a dictionary, and since both ints will be repeated, I can't swap them out. This idea also went out the window, same problem

```
Dictionary<int, int>[,] ItemList = new Dictionary<int, int>[4,4];
```

I also thought of using a **tuple**, and I don't have much(any) experience with it, and my experiments with them weren't going so well. The problem with it was I couldn't get the count of how many items were in it. I set one up like this.

```
Tuple<int, Point>[] ItemList = new Tuple<int, Point>[4];
```

Same Idea as my first example, Its just there is no code like this

```
ItemList[1].Count    /*OR*/     ItemList[1].Length
```

Please let me know if I am missing something terribly obvious with tuples, or suggest an different storage method that would be nice to have all 3 variables stored all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Using the idea of using a list, I solved my problem. Its kinda a hybrid between the suggested ideas and my original idea with using the array. You don't have to use an array if you are looking to do something similar, you can use a tuple with 3 values, I just needed an array for one int value because I needed them stored separately, based off of what that one int value was (between 0 and 4). Here is some code that would work.

```
        List<Tuple<int, Point>>[] ItemList = new List<Tuple<int, Point>>[4]; // how to declare it

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            ItemList[i] = new List<Tuple<int, Point>>(); // initilize each list
        }

        ItemList[1].Add(new Tuple<int, Point>(5, new Point(1, 2))); // add a new tuple to a specific array level

        int count = ItemList[1].Count; // finds the count for a specific level of the array --> (1)

        int getInt = ItemList[1].ElementAt(0).Item1; // finds int value --> (5)
        Point getPoint = ItemList[1].ElementAt(0).Item2; // finds the point --> (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Tuple` to store directly the 3 data structures. A `Tuple` can have more than two items, and of any type. That way, you don't have to use your array:

```
Tuple<int, int, Point>
```

To get the values, use the corresponding `Item` property. For the first int, it will be `yourTuple.Item1`. For the second one `yourTuple.Item2` and for the Point `yourTuple.Item3`.

If you have multiple `Tuples`, you can use a classic `List` to store them all:

```
var tuples = new List<Tuple<int, int, Point>>();
```

Since it's a list, you can get the count easily: `tuples.Count()`

Comment: I think I would still need the array for my purpose, since I need to examine only the ints with a certain value, and an array would be an easy way of doing so, but this is a good Idea. I will try some things with this.

Comment: The list is an `IEnumerable`, so you can use LINQ queries. If you only need the tuples with 2 as the first int, for example, use a `Where` query like `tuples.Where(t => t.Item1 == 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

So a `class` seems like the proper structure to me.

```
public class Something {

    public int Item1 { get; set; }
    public int Item2 { get; set; }
    public Point Location { get; set; }
}
```

Then you store these objects in a `List<>`

```
var List<Something> list = new List<Something>();
```

add items to the list...

```
list.Add(new Something() {Item1 = 4, Item2 = 8, Point = new Point(x,y)});
```

then use some LINQ to get just the ones you want.

```
var onlyItem1IsFour = (from item in list where 4 == item.Item1 select item).ToList();
```

*excuse my LINQ.  I'm used to VB and may have gotten the casing/syntax slightly wrong*